# Calculating the probabilities, for multiple candidates, of ranking first, and where those probabilities sum to 1, using ordinal logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, prediction, ordinal-data, ranking

First time poster on Cross Validated.

I'm trying to work out how to predict the winner of a race, of, for example, 5 contestants, where, for each of those contestants, I have 3 attributes, as X's, Age, Height and Sex.

As I am trying to predict the finishing rank of the contestants, ordinal logistic regression seems to be the most appropriate method.

However, having a read several articles on ordinal logistic regression, I cannot seem to work out a method of calculating the probability, which, when taking the probability or ratio of each contestant of winning, (and therefore achieving rank 1), the sums of which equal one, or unity.

eg.
I have 5 contestants...with the three X variables, age (in years), height(in cms), sex(binary, 0=Female, 1=Male)

1,17,168,1

2,18,146,0

3,15,167,1

4,17,155,0

5,16,164,1

and I have several hundred examples of earlier races with the same data points, plus the finishing rank of each contestant in that previous race.

Now, I assume, from what I have read, there should be a method, where, for example, contestant 1 has a 20% chance of winning (of being rank 1), contestant 2 has a 5% chance, contestant 3 has a 50% chance, and so on.... BUT where the sum of those same probabilities, across the 5 contestants, equals 1, or 100%.

I admit I am still learning this area of statistics, so I may be missing something fairly obvious.

I am running ordinal logistic regression using python code,  within MS SQL server 2019 with Machine Learning, and for the tutorials I've done so far, I can reproduce the data, but I cannot work out how to calculate the probabilities where the sum of the individual contestants probabilities of winning, i.e. obtaining rank 1, sum to 1.

I had a read of several of the "similar questions" as I crafted this question,
the most relevant was "How do perform conditional ordered logit / probit regression"
However, there wasn't any clear answer, to me at least, provided to the question.

I've also searched far and wide on this and other sites, without success, for the answer.

I also considered running a standard linear regression, using the same X values,and then, given the estimated predicted speed for each contestant, plus the standard error, there may be a way from that data to then calculate the same percentage likelihood that a given contestant will achieve rank 1, and therefore win the race...but the maths for that, well, to date, it eludes me.

I did notice that the some of the information I read in regards to the sum of the predictions equaling unity may have applied to multinomial logistic regression, and not specifically to ordinal logistic regression, but, to my admittedly limited knowledge, I would assume that if it is possible to achieve this with multinomial logistic regression, it should also be possible with ordinal logistic regression.

Any help, suggestions, or advice, greatly appreciated.
Thanks for reading.